# Where does Eclipse look for eclipse.ini under Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I've just been setting up a Ubuntu workstation and wanted to add some settings to eclipse.ini.  When I searched for the file I found:

- /etc/eclipse.ini
- /usr/lib/eclipse.ini

My questions are:

- Does Eclipse actually use both files?
- If so, in what order does it read them?
- How does it merge them?
- Both of the files I found are system wide, is there a location in my home directory I could put one that would effect only my instances?

Comment: Try `~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.,platform[...]/configuration/config.ini` where [...] is your version.

Comment: It turns out that the two eclipse.ini files are actually one file linked to two directories.

Comment: @JonStrayer It seems that's the answer to your question; if so, I recommend posting it as an answer. As you probably know, when no other answer covers your solution already, [it's encouraged to answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There is only one file.

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Aug  8  2012 /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse.ini -> /etc/eclipse.ini

Comment: This needs to be better documented.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 /etc$ sudo ls eclipse.ini cannot access eclipse.ini: No such file or directory for Eclipse Kepler August 2014 So this is not a sure fire answer

Comment: I found it under `/usr/share/eclipse/eclipse.ini` as Alexander Taylor mentioned.

Comment: For me it was in `/opt/eclipse`, see the "Here's how to determine which eclipse.ini file you should use" answer for how to find it if it's not there...

Comment: I found in ~/eclipse/eclipse.ini

Comment: Mine (ubuntu 16 with eclipse neon) was at /home/*username*/software/eclipse/

Answer (score 51):

Here's how to determine which eclipse.ini file you should use (joomla.org):

- If you downloaded Eclipse IDE manually from internet the "eclipse.ini" file is just inside the unpacked folder
- If you installed Eclipse via terminal or software center the location of the file is "/etc/eclipse.ini"
- In some Linux versions the file can be found at "/usr/share/eclipse/eclipse.ini".  Do **not** use this file if you found a config file at "/etc/eclipse.ini".

To be sure where your Eclipse folder is, check $ECLIPSE_HOME, and if not specified (these directions at least work for Juno):

- Open Eclipse as you normally do.
- Click Help -> About Eclipse SDK
- Click Installation Details
- Go to the Configuration tab
- Find "eclipse.home.location=file:*PATH*".  *PATH* is where eclipse is installed.

sources:

- http://docs.joomla.org/Configuring_Eclipse_IDE_for_PHP_development/Linux:

Comment: This should be the answer marked as correct. Mine was inside my unpackaged Eclipse folder.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 with Eclipse Neon, $ECLIPSE_HOME is at /home/*username*/software/eclipse/ (and it does indeed hold the eclipse.ini file that is launched)

Answer (score 2):

You probably have already found this out, chances are when you installed Eclipse the installation created (or you did manually) a file /usr/bin/eclipse which if you check it probably looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
export ECLIPSE_HOME="/opt/eclipse"

$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse $*
```

***especially*** if you followed instructions similar to the ones [like these](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/linux-install-eclipse-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) on If-not-true-then-false

On the other hand if you have installed from a package, I suspect you will find that eclipse ends up in /usr/bin, most likely a symbolic link to /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse (or at least I found it on my Fedora system after using yum to install eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

I have Ubuntu 18 and eclipse installation is squashed in a file

> /var/lib/snapd/snaps/eclipse_40.snap

which is mount on /snap/eclipse/40 as read only. Just run

```
mount | grep eclipse*.snap
```

This eclipse.ini file is really read only, that means, you cannot modify it, even with sudo. However, I also have a eclipse.ini.ignored file in HOME/.eclipse/*some number*/configuration. This is being by default ignored, but you can change the "launcher.ini" in the eclipse launcher command.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

> Eclipse startup is controlled by the options in
>   $ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse.ini. If $ECLIPSE_HOME is not defined, the
>   default eclipse.ini in your Eclipse installation directory (or in the
>   case of Mac, the Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS directory) is used.

Answer (score 0):

The certain way to make sure is to run strace on eclipse. In the output you'll see where is eclipse actually trying to pull the file from.