# Android emulator hangs when exporting a dependent jar

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

My android app was launching fine to both my HTC phone and my Android emulator until I added a jar to my build path to export with my project. Now when I try to run the app eclipse gets stuck at "Launching Tracker [my app]: 100%." I have tried restarting eclipse, uninstalling the ADT plugin and reinstalling, and just letting the launcher run for a while. Eventually it gives me the following error:

```
[2012-03-29 00:24:39 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
[2012-03-29 00:24:39 - Tracker] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I am currently using eclipse 3.7 and using SDK 2.1 for my app, and I have now tried to run the app on two different machines. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this error? Thank you!

Edit: If I don't check the box to export the dependent jar, then the launcher will run but the program immediately crashes because of a NoClassDefFoundError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to get the emulator to launch. As per http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/24227-ArcGIS-for-Android-gt-Eclipse-quot-out-of-memory-quot, I made the following changes to my `eclipse.ini` file:

```
-startup
....
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
.....
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
.....
```

Comment: Helped me, thanks. Still don't understand why I didn't have to do this on my other computer, but oh well.

Comment: Worked for me. For those of you who are using Linux and don't know where to find `eclipse.ini`, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419099/where-does-eclipse-look-for-eclipse-ini-under-linux).