# Can't open Eclipse, How to deal with it?

Tags: eclipse, fedora

I can't open Eclipse on my laptop, I'm using **Fedora 18**, 
it prompts a window which says:

```
    JVM terminated. Exit code=13
    /usr/bin/java
    -Xms128m
    -Xmx512m
    -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=true
    -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/core/internal/dtree/DataTreeNode,forwardDeltaWith
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedMethodBinding,<init>
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/dom/parser/cpp/semantics/CPPTemplates,instantiateTemplate
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/pdom/dom/cpp/PDOMCPPLinkage,addBinding
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/python/pydev/editor/codecompletion/revisited/PythonPathHelper,isValidSourceFile
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/python/pydev/ui/filetypes/FileTypesPreferencesPage,getDottedValidSourceFiles
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/tycho/core/osgitools/EquinoxResolver,newState
    -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
    -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
    -jar /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130701-1300.jar
    -os linux
    -ws gtk
    -arch x86_64
    -showsplash /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v20130701-1255/splash.bmp
    -launcher /usr/lib64/eclipse/eclipse
    -name Eclipse
    --launcher.library /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130701-1300/eclipse_1503.so
```

my java version

```
    [kai@kitty kai]$ java -version
    java version "1.7.0_60"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (fedora-2.4.2.0.fc18-i386)
    OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

the content of eclipse.ini is:

the content of eclipse.ini is:

```
    -preventMasterEclipseLaunch
    -startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130701-1300.jar
    --launcher.library
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130701-1300
    -showsplash
    org.eclipse.platform
    --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    256m
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    -vmargs
    -Xms128m
    -Xmx512m

    -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=true
    -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/core/internal/dtree/DataTreeNode,forwardDeltaWith
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedMethodBinding,<init>
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/dom/parser/cpp/semantics/CPPTemplates,instantiateTemplate
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/pdom/dom/cpp/PDOMCPPLinkage,addBinding
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/python/pydev/editor/codecompletion/revisited/PythonPathHelper,isValidSourceFile
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/python/pydev/ui/filetypes/FileTypesPreferencesPage,getDottedValidSourceFiles
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/tycho/core/osgitools/EquinoxResolver,newState
    -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
```

I'm at a loss on what to do.
How to deal with this problem?

Comment: post the eclipse.ini file, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13

Comment: There is still a `eclipse.ini` file. Where does it exists? Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419099/where-does-eclipse-look-for-eclipse-ini-under-linux

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this (from another answer):

1. Check if the jvm is 64 or 32 bit. java -version will tell you. If you find this is a 64-bit jvm then go back to eclipse.org and download a eclipse version for 64-bit. You have eclipse for a 32-bit jvm. See your error message where it says -arch x86
2. Try to start eclipse from a shell using the -vm parameter. On ubuntu you can find the installed jre/jdk's under /var/lib/jvm/. E.g.:

./eclipse -vm /var/lib/jvm/sun-java6-jdk/bin

You could add this parameter to your eclipse.ini file.

Say something!

Comment: The `-arch x86_64` line in the trace shows that OP has a 64 bit Eclipse (as does the `--launcher.library` plugin name). So this probably a 32 bit JVM.

Comment: I'm using linux, there is no eclipse.ini, how to find `jre/jdk's`? thanks

Comment: @user3131513 There is an `eclipse.ini` when using eclipse under linux. Try running `$ locate eclipse.ini`

Comment: I found it, but how to tune it?