# Eclipse always try to starts with /root/workspace

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I have posted the question in [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/416653/eclipse-always-starts-with-root-workspace-in-ubuntu) but have not gotten any reply so far.

Eclipse is always try to start with `/root/workspace` . I select `~/workspace` and check that I want to use this workspace only. But on every restart eclipse is trying to open with `/root/workspace` . If I create other workspaces with different name and select that permanently then also after restart it is trying to open /root/workspace.

Eclipse : Kepler

Ubuntu: 12.04 LTS

Comment: Just a guess (I have currently no Ubuntu or eclipse at hand): [Check where your `eclipse.ini` is located](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419099/where-does-eclipse-look-for-eclipse-ini-under-linux) and see who is the owner of that file and if you are allowed to write to that file.

Comment: It's owned by me only.
-rwxrwxrwx 1 reuben reuben 449 Feb  5 12:48 eclipse.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go under preferences then type "`workspace`" in the search box provided
  to filter the list. Alternatively you can go to **General>Startup and
  Shutdown>Workspaces**.
- There you can set a flag to make Eclipse prompt you to select a
  workspace at startup by checking the "**Prompt for workspace at
  startup**" checkbox.
- You can set the number of previous workspaces to remember also.
  Finally there is a list of recent workspaces. If you just remove all
  but the one you want Eclipse will automatically startup with that
  workspace.