# eclipse.ini has been changed, but eclipse wont updated in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

First, i have done a lot of research and this is the answer i think the best :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17498043/1203797

According to that answer, my `eclipse.ini` should be on the **same** directory of my eclipse because i downloded it from the internet (**not** via `terminal/software center`).

I need to change the RAM used by my eclipse because i keep getting `GC overheat error` when trying to run a big application.

This is my `eclipse.ini` :

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
2048m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
```

Note that i have updated the `Xmx/Xms` value, but :

```
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-vm
/usr/bin/java
eclipse.home.location=file:/home/tama/DEVELOPMENT/adt-bundle/eclipse/
eclipse.launcher=/home/tama/DEVELOPMENT/adt-bundle/eclipse/eclipse
eclipse.launcher.name=Eclipse
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/
eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.jee
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
eclipse.startTime=1417076772881
eclipse.stateSaveDelayInterval=30000
eclipse.vm=/usr/bin/java
eclipse.vmargs=-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

That is what displayed in `Eclipse Installation Detail` (I know this from the **answer** i posted above).

Please kindly help me, Thanks for your time.

Comment: The eclipse.ini only changes the memory used by Eclipse. When you run an application from Eclipse the values in 'Run > Run Configurations' for the app are used.

Comment: @greg-449 Sorry, what do you mean? I did a lot of research and people said i need to change the `xms/xmx` to overcome the `GC` error...please kindly help me :)

Comment: If you are running a program from Eclipse you must put the XMS/XMX values in the Run configuration for the program

Comment: @greg-449 How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I spent hours, now i want to cry and laugh at the same time.

The shortcut that in the ubuntu's launcher does **not** use the `eclipse.ini` in the eclipse's directory, eventhough it linked to the same `eclipse`.

I need to run the eclipse from the directory **manually** or create a shortcut to the desktop, then the `eclipse.ini` will be readed

Comment: you can run eclipse from command line directly. I think you should call with "clean" command. like, "eclipse clean"

Comment: @Adem Thanks, but tried clean..it has no effect, i need to run the eclipse directly from the directory

Comment: Thank you, you saved me tons of hours!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, we found out the Ubuntu launcher created a desktop entry file with different runtime arguments than the ones specified in the eclipse.ini.

What we ended up doing was editing the "eclipse.desktop" launcher file :

1. Find Eclipse's launcher file using `locate eclipse.desktop`
2. Edit the file in a text editor (nano \ vi \ gedit \ etc)
3. change the jvm arguments for the "java" command.

Answer (score 1):

As other users noted, the problem is that eclipe.desktop file, located at ~/.local/share/applications/ folder, contains its own initialization parameters, and basically ignores whatever is in the eclipse.ini file.

So, while just using the executable in the eclipse folder is a good solution, it doesn't let you use the launcher shortcut.

What I did was edit the contents of eclipse.desktop, and changed the Exec entry so it looks like this:

```
Exec=/full/path/to/elipse/eclipse
```

That way the launcher just runs the executable, and eclipse.ini is read normally.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu start `eclipse` and lock it to the Launcher.
Now edit the file `~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`
and add `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` just after `Exec=/usr/bin/java`.
See my file below.

This works great for me.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=C/C++ - Eclipse
Icon=eclipse.png
Path=/opt/eclipse
Exec=/usr/bin/java -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms40m -Xmx512m -jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -showsplash /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.0.v20130605-2000/splash.bmp -launcher /opt/eclipse/eclipse -name Eclipse --launcher.library /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130521-0416/eclipse_1506.so -startup /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar --launcher.appendVmargs -exitdata 258000 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product -vm /usr/bin/java -vmargs -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms40m -Xmx512m -jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```