# how to edit eclipse.ini file from command prompt - ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, command-prompt

My program shows  Exception : GC overhead limit exceeded . I found one solution as , to increase the eclipse heap size in eclipse.ini.I tried to open eclipse.ini from Ubuntu command prompt using the command given below

```
sudo gedit /usr/bin/eclipse/etc/eclipse.ini
```

But this is not working..it just opens a new gedit file named eclipse.ini..
How can i open eclipse.ini in Ubuntu command prompt and edit

Comment: if it does not work that means the path you specified to `eclipse.ini` is invalid.

Comment: yaa.it works now..but i couldnt save the file..i tried to change the file permissions using- sudo chown your_username:your_username filename , in this what is the filename to be given

Comment: i managed to change the file permission using sudo chmod -R o+rw /usr/bin and could save the file .. but now also same GC overhead problem exists

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use the following command from a terminal:

```
locate eclipse.ini
```

You will know the exact location of eclipse.ini and will be able to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried finding the existing file and editing it? Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419099/where-does-eclipse-look-for-eclipse-ini-under-linux) for more details on where to find the file on Linux, then edit it.

Answer (score 0):

The 'eclipse.ini' file is always in the same directory as the eclipse executable in your Eclipse installation. This is normally the root directory of the installation, not 'etc'.

Comment: ya..i changed the path..and now it is working..btwn how can i save this eclipse.ini file with the changed heap size..save option seems to be disabled for this file

Comment: Sorry but I'm not really an Ubuntu expert. Something to do with file permissions possibly.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gedit /opt/eclipse/eclipse.ini
```

Comment: Your answer certainly is worth a little explanation. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .