# Eclipse hangs while creating a node.js express project

Tags: eclipse, node.js

I have Eclipse 3.7 on Windows XP. I have also installed NodeEclipse. I can create a regular node project fine. But when I try to create a new express project, eclipse just hands and I cannot even close the window. Killing the process is the only option. Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 1):

Get the latest version of eclipse, and run it using the latest version of JDK, first off.

You can also configure your eclipse.ini to allow it to use more memory.

Here is an answer to another question that had a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2610261/1073118

Just note that it depends on your system, and whether your eclipse is 32bit or 64bit