# Eclipse quick view works but not outline

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse juno i can view the outline of XML/java files from outline view. i can also see the drop down menu options for the outline view.

the problem i have is that for some XML files i get "an outline is not available"  message in the outline view, and the drop down menu options disappear. but Quick view still works for the current XML file but outline view shows an error.

i think this maybe an issue with eclipse, i have to restart eclipse about every few hours because it visually starts bugging out (lines of code disappearing when clicked on, but not actually deleted) . this is also a fresh installation of eclipse juno with just Android SDK.

Here is my eclipse workspace log. http://pastebin.com/WJr10Rqz

Comment: Please remove the XML tag as this is not an XML related question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a memory issue. Please consult: [How can I give eclipse more memory than 512M?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610194/how-can-i-give-eclipse-more-memory-than-512m)

If this doesn't help you, please include your Eclipse workspace's logs (located at your {workspace}/.metadata directory) for further investigation.

**EDIT**: The solution seems to be to update Eclipse to Kepler.

Comment: Ive Upped the amount of Ram eclipse can use, hopefully that helps with the disappearing text issue. but it did not help with the Outline issue, i have posted my workspace log.

Comment: Did you create a new workspace when installing your Eclipse or did you migrate an old one?

Comment: i do have old workspaces that Ive used with this new installation of eclipse, but that log i posted is from the new workspace with the issue that i am having.

Comment: OK. Did you try a newer Eclipse?