# Increase ADT memory

Tags: android, eclipse, memory-management, adt

My android project is taking a long time to build. After doing some research, the answer seems to be to increase the memory available to eclipse with such example as

eclipse -vmargs -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m

I am using a mac osx lion. And my eclipse is ADT. I find this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610194/how-can-i-give-eclipse-more-memory-than-512m) for a shortcut. But I can't seem to find that screen. Does anyone know a quick way for doing this (the instructions, I mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to your ADT directory where Eclipse is located (in finder).  Right click on Eclipse.app -> Show Package Contents.  In the .app navigate to Contents->MacOS->Open eclipse.ini, edit as necessary.

i.e. Change the lines -Xms40m and -Xmx768m to whatever you like.  Save the file and relaunch eclipse.

Comment: thanks. This still didn't solve the underlying problem of speeding android apk build time.

Comment: I had faced that problem before and it was a pain to find.  Glad I could help!