# Eclipse freezes on android project build

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've tried to create a new project on android and ran it without any problem in my emulator.

I added the `google-play-service library` in my eclipse workbench and linked it to my project. Then I tried to run it again and my eclipse started loading... Then the progress bar stopped to move, then I saw eclipse took 80% of my CPU capacity! So I shut it down and tried again, same thing happened.

For your info I imported the `google-play-service library` from

`sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib`

and I still have not touched the example code in the `MainActivity.java`

Comment: What's in the logcat?

Comment: Nothing shows up. It's blank. Eclipse stays stuck at 'launching test_app'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue on my own PC (Windows) by allocating more memory for Eclipse. Add this to your properties if you're on Windows (you can give the same command line arguments in linux).

[image: Eclipse properties]

Taken from this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610194/how-can-i-give-eclipse-more-memory-than-512m)

Comment: Oh that's it ! I finally got an error. Eclipse stopped trying to compile and returned an error:
"Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
Unhandled event loop exception
workbench auto-save job
GC overhead limit exceeded"

Comment: Yup, that means you need to increase allocated your eclipse memory. Glad I could help. Make sure your shortcut to eclipse is executing those command line properties properly.