# GC overhead limit exceeded with google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to run my android project on eclipse and platform ubuntu 64 bit. Everything goes well but When I Add Google play Services to the project appear a big problem.

1.Running android app, hight CPU load.

[image]

2. Eclipse Show wrong message "GC overhead limit exceeded".

[image]

3. Finally Close Eclipse.

[image]

When remove google play from my prject, it can running well.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using android studio instead of eclipse https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.

But also, you could try launching eclipse with more memory: [How can I give eclipse more memory than 512M?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610194/how-can-i-give-eclipse-more-memory-than-512m)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add everything from google play services to your project? If so, I suggest you only depend on the APIs that your project actually uses.

See [Selectively compiling APIs into your executable](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) page