# How do I optimise my ini file so that my Eclipse Kepler 32bit performs faster- I'm using Windows 7 64bit 6GB RAM

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

How do I optimise the performance of my Eclipse Kepler 32bit- I'm using Windows 7 64bit 6GB RAM. Here is my current ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```

Is my ini file optimised correctly?

Comment: You always "optimize" towards a certain goal; so your question does not make any sense in the real world. And for the record: the best way to "optimize" your Eclipse experience is by working with a more recent version. In other words: install Neon. And learn which pluggins are really essential to improve your workflow; and from there, maybe go backwards and figure if you can "improve" that setup by looking into the ini file; which honestly: I doubt you have to. Besides: your question is way too broad/unclear.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i modified my question to make it clearer. i ideally want to stick with kepler 32bit if possible.

Comment: If by performance you mean processing power, you won't be able to take advantage of your 64 bit CPU if you decide to use the 32 bit version of eclipse. On the other hand, if you mean more memory, please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610194/how-can-i-give-eclipse-more-memory-than-512m .

Comment: Also, as I see, you cannot assign more than 2GB of RAM to an application that's build on 32 bit - see details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639540/how-much-memory-can-a-32-bit-process-access-on-a-64-bit-operating-system .