# Java - print 1 billion to 2 billion

Tags: java, memory

I wanted to print out 1 000 000 000 to 1 999 999 999.
I thought it would be an easy task but eclipse tells me something about memory error. How could I do this? I want to have a text data where all numbers from
1000000000 to 1999999999 are written down each in a new line. I thought printing them out in the console and then just copy & paste into a .txt data would work, but it sadly doesn't.

My code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 1000000000;
    do {
        System.out.println(number);
        number = number +1;
    } while (number < 2000000000);

}
```

How would you fix this problem?
Please help me.

Comment: This could would work right. Is the problem you facing is with the size of the data?

Comment: In case if Eclipse goes out of memory try to increase memory in eclipse.

Comment: After counting from 1 000 000 000 it stops somewhere at 1 006 000 000.
I can't even copy it from the console. I don't understand what the issue is.

@Rangas: How to increase Eclipse's memoy?

wenzi: How to print out directly to a .txt file?

Comment: Check this link to update eclipse memory settings. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610194/how-can-i-give-eclipse-more-memory-than-512m

Comment: Dude!  Do you _really_ need to print out **a billion** ten-digit numbers to prove that you've mastered using a `do...while` loop to count out a range of numbers?   Why not just start at 100 and go up to, say, 1000?  Just sayin'...

Comment: Or assuming this is not about mastering loops, but you really need a list of a billion numbers for something, a text file is probably not the best way to store those. What do you need to do with them next?

Comment: Yes, I **really** need to print out a billion ten-digit numbers. Not to prove anything.
I couldn't open it with the standard editor. But found: https://www.emeditor.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wrote this piece of code and by running it I got the following results:

- **Final file:** 10GB+
- **Start time**:     Sat Oct 06 00:00:19 BRT 2018
- **Finishing time**: Sat Oct 06 00:03:25 BRT 2018

  ```
   try { 
      FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("count.txt");
      System.out.println(new Date());
      int number = 1000000000;
      do {
          writer.write(number + "\n");
      } while (number++ < 2000000000);
      System.out.println(new Date());
      writer.close(); 
  } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I tried it out, but my editor can't open the file.
Do you know an editor which can handle this amount of data?

Comment: more than 3 *minutes*, not hours

Comment: @Thilo Yeah, sorry. It's 5.00 am where I live. I should go to bed.

Comment: @CoreNoob the file will be saved in the root folder of your project

Answer (score 5):

The problem you are encountering is because you are asking Eclipse to buffer 1,000,000,000 x 11 or 12 characters in memory.  That is > 20 GB, and it is clearly too large for the Eclipse processes heap.

That approach simply won't work, unless you are running Eclipse on a really high-end PC with a huge amount of RAM.   Even then, I have my doubts.  For example, copy-and-paste of 10 billion characters probably wouldn't work.

You need to take another approach; e.g. have your application write the numbers directly to the output file.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to run the class file from command line and redirect the output. Assuming you are running on "unixy" kind of environment.

`java Counter > output.txt # This will take lot of time.`

Comment: According to the other poster, not a terrible lot of time, on the order of a couple of minutes (and tens of GB of disk space). :-)