# Eclipse performance problems with Visual Paradigm integration

Tags: eclipse, performance, cpu, visual-paradigm

I installed Visual Paradigm IDE integration in Eclipse. When I'm using Visual Paradigm in Eclipse, Eclipse suddenly uses a lot of CPU power and has performance problems. I tested the IDE integration with Netbeans and there I have no problem.

You can see the amount of CPU power here, both have the integraded Visual Paradigm open.
[image]

Here are my pc specs (DELL XPS 13 9370)
[image]

Any suggestions I can do to solve this? I rather use Eclipse than Netbeans fyi.

Comment: NetBeans has more than twice of memory. You might increase your memory settings in Eclipse. If this does not help, tell your findings to the plugin vendor.

Comment: I changed the minimum memory from -Xms256m to -Xms1024m and the max was already -Xmx2048m in the file eclipse.ini like they suggest here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610194/how-can-i-give-eclipse-more-memory-than-512m, but that didn't change anything. As you said, maybe I should contact Visual Paradigm. Thanks.